# Problems with implementation of concatenation function in C

Tags: c, string, concatenation

I am still new to pointers in C and have been trying to make string functions. This one is supposed to concatenate two strings, but when I try to run it, it crashes.

```
void concatenate (char *a, char *b, int size_a, int size_b) {
    char *c, *d, *e;
    c = a;
    d = b;
    int i, j, k;
    int l = 1;

    for(i = 0; i<size_a; i++) {
        *(e+i) = *(c+i);
    }
    for (j = size_a; j<size_a+size_b; j++) {
        *(e+j) = *(d+(j-(j-l)));
        l++;
    }
    for (k = 0; k< size_a+size_b; k++){
        printf("%c",*(e+k));
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Crashes your compiler?  Really?  Can you show the error message?

Comment: Not only that your function takes `char *a` and `char *b` as parameters (meaningless names), but its body even starts with `char *c, *d, *e; c = a; d = b;`

Comment: Hint - `e` doesn't point at anything.

Comment: Well I would like e to point to the new string. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: ... allocate some memory for it?

Comment: `for(idx = strlen(a), jdx =0; idx < max_a_size -1; idx++, jdx++) *(a + idx) = *(b + jdx); *(a + idx) = '\0';`

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strncat.3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the memory where uninitialized pointer `e` points to, which leads to **undefined behavior**.

Your function should look like this:

```
char* concatenate (const char *a, const char *b, int size_a, int size_b) {
    // create new string:
    char* newStr = malloc (size_a + size_b + 1);
    int i, j;

    // copy first string into it:
    for (i = 0; i<size_a; i++)
        newStr[i] = a[i];

    // copy second string into it:
    for (j = 0; j < size_b; j++)
        newStr[i + j] = b[j];

    newStr[i + j] = '\0';
    return newStr;
}
```

Note that function doesn't change strings that are passed to it, thus they can be passed as `const`. The `size_a` and `size_b` are expected to be equal to `strlen(a)` and `strlen(b)`, which also means that in case you always pass null-terminated strings into this function, you can calculate their length on your own within its body (so you can get rid of last 2 arguments).

Comment: How do I get it so "concatenate" returns a new string?

Comment: Shouldn't the count of size_a and size_b include the null terminator.  Then the malloc size parameter should be set to (size_a + size_b - 1).

Comment: @TallSoftwareDude: That's explained in the lines under the code.

Comment: @user2041197: You're welcome :) Also don't forget to call `free` on the pointer returned from `concatenate` function. You should `free` the memory that has been allocated by `malloc` once you don't need this memory anymore.

Answer (score 0):

e is an uninitialized pointer, which means it is pointing to some random place in memory.  When you start writing to it as if it were a pointer to a character array, your program will crash (or worse, change some state mysteriously causing unspecified behavior later on).

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems obfuscated for no reason. The problem is that you're assigning to `e`, which is uninitialized. The following is, pretty much, your code in a more readable form and with `e` allocated. I haven't tested it, though.

```
void concatenate (char *c, char *d) {    
    char *e; 
    e = calloc(strlen(c) + strlen(d) + 1, sizeof(char));
    int i, j;
    int l = 1;

    for(i = 0; c[i]; i++) {
        e[i] = c[i];
    }
    l = i;
    for (j = 0; d[j]; j++) {
        e[l + j] = d[j];
    }
    e[l + j] = '\0';

    printf("%s", e);

    free(e);
}
```

Comment: the original passes in the string sizes. it is the norm, but how do you know that the strings are null terminated?